# Removing GPL files from a dual-licensed project with LGPL

Tags: gpl, lgpl

I'm using a GitHub project dual-licensed under GPL and LGPL (some files are GPL and some are LGPL). That's why it has two files with its license terms and conditions "COPYING" and "COPYING.LESSER". To stick to the LGPL terms only, I removed all the GPL-licensed files. Now, considering the project can be built and used with just the LGPL files, is it permitted to delete the COPYING file and retain only COPYING.LESSER?

Comment: Why not just get the libraries directly from the people who distribute them, and avoid any uncertainty?  Or are you saying this is all from one project which does not make that distinction in its distribution?

Comment: If it is a public GitHub project, it might as well be helpful to link that here.

Comment: Which GPL/LGPL versions? The LGPLv3 is implemented as an extension of the GPLv3, not as a stand-alone license. It is very confusing to me that you're talking about a dual-licensed project (which implies you already have a choice of licenses), but also about files that are only under GPL and not LGPL.